# Dockerfile error when running update && upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dockerfile, fedora

I am building my first dockerfile and need to install some packages. Presently I am using Fedora and the first thing I would like to do is run dnf update && upgrade, but I get an error.

Dockerfile:

```
# Base image
FROM fedora:28
LABEL description="Intellij community edition 2018"

# Update and Upgrade
RUN dnf update && upgrade -y
```

Error:

```
Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'updates'
The command '/bin/sh -c dnf update && upgrade -y' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I have tried with both dnf and yum, and also used ubuntu as a base image so I could try with apt-get, but I keep getting a different but similar Error:

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
/bin/sh: 1: upgrade: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && upgrade -y' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

I have already tried the solution to these questions, but neither worked:

[The command '/bin/sh -c returned a non-zero code: 127](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876031/the-command-bin-sh-c-returned-a-non-zero-code-127)

[How to install multiple packages using apt-get via a Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273087/how-to-install-multiple-packages-using-apt-get-via-a-dockerfile)

The only way I can get this to run is by building manually from an empty container using the -net=host argument.

Is it even possible to install, update or upgrade packages directly from the docker file, and if so how?

Comment: How do you call ``docker build``?

Comment: docker build -t dockerfile .

Comment: Note that ``apt-get update && upgrade -y`` is not valid, since ``upgrade`` is not an existing ubuntu command. You probably meant ``apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y``. That doesn't fix your name resolution problem though.

Comment: I will correct that and I'l keep messing about to see if I can stumble upon a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a short while off on another project, I have come back to learning docker. I am still unsure what was causing the errors. But when building the dockerfile I have been using a different name and tag, as I had deleted the image/container list. I can only assume it was a clash with a reserved word of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

I remember this just vaguely but still enough to set it down here, that you should not upgrade. `&& upgrade -y` is just not needed since the image and the update should be all that is needed, else, you would rather install a higher version in that image right from the start, or take a higher version of the image. Therefore you have the image, that you choose a bag of versions that fit together, and upgrading can lead to version conflicts as in `Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'updates'`.