# Getting error while installing package in docker image

Tags: azure, docker, installation, fonts, package

The beginning of this error is from creating and password based image in Azure environment. Below is the origin or this all. More info on this I just got to know we are using alpine based image.openjdk:8uX-alpine311
[image: X11FontManager]

So I did googled a bit and found some package needs to be installed and to do that I need to execute below command.
`RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y fontconfig libfreetype6` which resulted me in

> the command bin/sh sh returned a non zero code 127

After further analysis I found another solution to this is to run below query.
`RUN apk add --update fontconfig libfreetype6` as result again came as

> the command bin/sh sh returned a non zero code 2

I am wondering this is just some package installation on azure environment, what it takes every time change in command's. Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
the command bin/sh sh returned a non zero code 127
```

Means the command wasn't found. Which is correct, since you're using an `alpine` image and `apt-get` is mostly found in `debian` based images. See also [command '/bin/sh -c returned a non-zero code: 127](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876031/the-command-bin-sh-c-returned-a-non-zero-code-127)

Testing your command on an local `alpine:3.11` image I can verify that the command fails when trying to install `libfreetype6`

Try `RUN apk add --update fontconfig freetype`

You can verify if a package is available by checking [pkgs.alpinelinux.org](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=freetype&branch=v3.11&repo=main&arch=x86)

Comment: OK. Let me check by adding in docker file.

Comment: But again while deploying build on Develop it failed
The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --update fontconfig freetype' returned a non-zero code: 2

Comment: Hard to say since I can't find your image to test myself, but what you could do is try to run `docker run -ti --rm image.openjdk:8uX-alpine311 ash` and then run `apk add --update` manually and try to debug from inside the container.

Comment: ok. Since this everything is organized by our org i dont know .. How much i can go inside .

Comment: Proxy was disabled at my end hence Command couldn't get executed in morning deops changed config , now build is successful and new error is introduced.
.l.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/java.64/jre/lib/amd64/libfontmanager.so: libfreetype.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory